# Match the content within a tag from a Non-HTML response in URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module, outbound

When going through a proxy server (A), any self-referential links sent from the apps server (B) need to be re-written to use the proxy as a host instead.

Here's an example:

Response from (B) contains: `<a href="http://apps/path">path</a>`
Proxy (A) needs to rewrite as: `<a href="http://proxy/path">path</a>`

Normally, this is done by creating an outbound rule that inspects html responses for tags that contain urls, looks for references to to the apps server, and rewrites them.

**Here's a normal rule** <sup>[*GUI version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaewx.png)</sup>:

```xml
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Outbound Links" preCondition="IsHTML" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A, Form, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="(https?:\/\/proxy|^)\/(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http://apps/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
```

**Where `IsHTML` is defined as**:

```xml
<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="IsHTML">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="text\/html" />
    </preCondition>
```

**The problem** is that some of the page content is returned via an XHR request.  Minimally, this fails the HTML precondition.

[image: Content Type - text/html vs XHR]

but I can expand the rule to also include content types of `xhr`

However, URL Rewrite still has trouble **parsing** the returned text into tags because it is not valid HTML.

Here's an example of what the response looks like:

```http
|6383|updatePanel|ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_contentUpdatePanel|

<div id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_resultsPanel">
   <a href="http://apps/path">path</a>   
</div>

...

|0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||0|hiddenField|
```

However, when I do this, I get the error:

> **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException**:
>   The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify XHR requests coming back from the ASP.NET. Doing so would be to attempt a Man In The Middle Attack (which your proxy is acting as), but Microsoft has good reason to prevent.

Here's a dummy message to explore the syntax ASP.NET uses in the response:

```
1|#||2|52|updatePanel|ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_firstUpdatePanel|
    <p> New Content For First Update Panel </p>
```

The header starts with `1|#| |` and then the number of updates in the rest of the message (2)
Then each update section follows the pattern:

```
|char_len|update_type|id_of_field_to_update|   
New contents to insert into field
```

The `len` in each section must exactly equal the number of characters to follow.  So finding and replacing content in these messages is extremely fickle.

The best recommendation is to simply return a relative URL that is server agnostic so the client can be redirected relative to their current domain.